# RAM memory card for Toshiba Satellite c55

Tags: laptop, memory

I'd like to upgrade the RAM memory on a Toshiba Satellite C55-B5115KM, which presently has a 4 GB card.
The laptop specifications I have found for the card type are PC3-2800 or 8500 or 10600, DDR3L SODIMM 204 pin.
I'd like to install a card I took from a Dell Inspiron N5110, which has 16 GB and its specifications are PC3-10600 DDR3 SDRAM SODIMM 204 pin.
I have found a discrepancy in the information about the Tohiba laptop as to how much RAM it can use. Some site says 8 GB some says 16 GB in two cards.
So my question is if what I want do is possible or if I can install 2 8 GB cards or limit it to 1 8 GB card or two 4 GB cards.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're not sure, don't guess. See Super User - [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: The information I listed in my post comes from one of the sites suggested in the link you provided.

Comment: So why wasn't it sufficient? If they list it on the page for your computer, it will work.

Comment: Because some sites say one it can use 8 GB of RAM and other 16 GB. Also, I cannot find whether the laptop has 1 or 2 slots for memory cards.